# Clojure spec for a single key in a map

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I'm speccing http responses from [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors)
and I want different specs for each response type.

I've defined a spec for HTTP response as

```clj
(s/def ::http-resp
  (s/keys :req-un [:status] :opt-un [:body]))
```

But how do I define a spec for each HTTP status?
I know I can do `:s.http-error-401/status`, but I would prefer something like

```clj
(s/and ::http-response 
       (key-in-a-map :status :s.http-statuses.error/gone))
```

Maybe there's an example of good specs for HTTP responses?
I've found only [ring-spec](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-spec/blob/master/src/ring/core/spec.clj) so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO `ring-spec` already serve your purpose.  You can find the spec for HTTP status there:

```
(s/def :ring.response/status (s/int-in 100 600))
```

Note that HTTP status code is a number. If you need to fine tune the spec, you can always do something like this:

```clj
(def ^:const OK 200)
(def ^:const UNAUTHORIZED 401)

(s/def ::status #{OK UNAUTHORIZED})

(s/def ::body string?)

(s/def ::response (s/keys :req-un [::status] :opt [::body]))

(s/valid? ::response {:status 200
                      :body   "Hello"})
;; => true


(s/valid? ::response {:status 1000
                      :body   "Hello"})
;; => false
```

**Updated based on comment from 2021.09.26**

You can also define each return code as individual spec and combine them with `or`.  Then you can use `conform` to get the code:

```
(s/def ::status (status-spec [200 OK
                              400 BAD_REUEST
                              404 NOT_FOUND]))

(s/def ::response (s/keys :req-un [::status] :opt [::body]))

(s/conform ::response {:status 200
                       :body "Hello"})
;; => {:status [:user/OK 200], :body "Hello"}

(s/conform ::status 200)
;; => [:user/OK 200]
```

Macro to make defining individual return code spec easier:

```
(defn- destructure-kv [kvs]
  (let [xs (partition 2 kvs)]
    (interleave (map (comp (partial keyword (str *ns*))
                           str
                           last)
                     xs)
                (map (comp set vector first) xs))))

(defmacro status-spec [kvs]
  `(s/or ~@(destructure-kv kvs)))
```

which basically generate an `or`:

```
(status-spec [200 OK
              400 BAD_REUEST
              404 NOT_FOUND])

=>

(s/or :user/OK #{200} 
      :user/BAD_REUEST #{400} 
      :user/NOT_FOUND #{404})
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! But for some instances I want this http-response to have an exact status. Let's say I'm writing a test for http POST
In some cases I want the response to have `:status 403`
In others `:status 200`.

The way I understand spec – is that I'll have to either check 2 specs, or define another s/keys spec that will have a `::req-un [:my.http.s400/status]`

Comment: Please see updated section